# How to open new window with push button

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

How do I open a new window which allows me to select the time from the following code? I tried to use connect function to connect to windows2 however it appears that there is an error.

I would like to select time by a dropbox where I could choose time by 10 am, 11 am, ect.. Does anyone know how you could implement this as well?

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.label = QLabel()
        self.calendar = QCalendarWidget()
        self.title="Select date from calendar"
        self.left = 600
        self.top = 300
        self.width = 500
        self.height = 480
        self.iconName = "home.png"
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(self.iconName))
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.proceedbutton = QPushButton("Proceed to select time", self)
        self.proceedbutton.setGeometry(290, 430, 190, 40)
        self.proceedbutton.setToolTip("<h3>Start the Session</h3>")
        self.proceedbutton.clicked.connect(self.window2)

        self.hide()

        self.backbutton = QPushButton("Back", self)
        self.backbutton.setGeometry(200, 430, 80, 40)
        self.backbutton.setToolTip("<h3>Start the Session</h3>")

        self.Calendar()
        self.show()

    def Calendar(self):
        CalendarVbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.calendar.setGridVisible(True)

        self.label.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Sanserif", 10))
        self.label.setStyleSheet('color:black')
        CalendarVbox.addWidget(self.calendar)
        CalendarVbox.addWidget(self.label)

        self.setLayout(CalendarVbox)
        self.calendar.selectionChanged.connect(self.onSelectionChanged)

    def window2(self):
        self.label = QLabel("Select Time", self)
        self.label.move(200,430)
        self.setWindowTitle("Select Time")
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.show()

    def onSelectionChanged(self):
        ca = self.calendar.selectedDate()
        self.label.setText(ca.toString())

App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start using **layouts**!

A widget without a parent - there is a window.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Window(QWidget):         #(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title="Select date from calendar"
        self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height  = 600, 100, 500, 480
        self.iconName = "Ok.png"             # <--- home.png
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(self.iconName))
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.calendar = QCalendarWidget()
        self.calendar.setGridVisible(True)
        self.calendar.selectionChanged.connect(self.onSelectionChanged)

        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Sanserif", 10))
        self.label.setStyleSheet('color: blue;')

        self.proceedbutton = QPushButton("Proceed to select time", self)
        self.proceedbutton.setToolTip("<h3>Start the Session</h3>")
        self.proceedbutton.clicked.connect(self.window2)

        self.backbutton = QPushButton("Back", self)
        self.backbutton.setToolTip("<h3>Start the Session</h3>")

        self.comboBox = None

        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.calendar, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.backbutton, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.proceedbutton, 2, 2, 1, 1)

    def window2(self):
        self.window = QWidget() 
        self.window.setWindowTitle("Select Time")
        self.window.setGeometry(self.left/3, self.top, self.width/3, self.height/3)

        self.label = QLabel("Select Time")                       # --- , self)

        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.comboBox.addItems(["choose time", "10", "11", "12"])       
        self.comboBox.activated[str].connect(self.onComboActivated)

        layout = QFormLayout(self.window)
        layout.addRow('Choose Time', self.comboBox)

        self.window.show()

    def onSelectionChanged(self):
        ca = self.calendar.selectedDate()
        self.label.setText(ca.toString())

    def onComboActivated(self, text):
        print("choose time: {}".format(text))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

[image]